# How to send cloudwatch metrics data to kinesis data stream

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-kinesis, amazon-cloudwatch-metrics

I am trying to send the perfmon data such as memory, disk space, CPUtilization data points to kinesis data stream.

in order to do that I installed CW agent on the EC2 instance and created a CW log group. the log group is subscribed to the kinesis stream.
I can see the metrics getting populated in the CW however I don't have a way to send these metrics to the kinesis and the logs which are pushed to the stream doesn't help in my next steps.

Is there a straight forward way to send the metrics data to kinesis? I don't want to add an extra layer of script in between.
Please suggest!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not directly stream CloudWatch metrics (data-points) to a Kinesis stream.

CloudWatch Logs you can, by creating a subscription filter on the LogGroup with Kinesis.

For most of the use cases involving metrics the API GetMetricData or GetMetricStatistic should be enough.

Answer (score 1):

Cloudwatch now supports writing to a Kinesis https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/CloudWatch-Metric-Streams.html. The data can then be further manipulated and shipped using a lambda with the kinesis stream as a trigger.